# Django Query for Total Count of Records In ManyToMany Field

Tags: django, django-models

Given two models joined by a ManyToMany without a through table:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)
```

How do I find the total count of instances of an ingredient being used in a recipe?

For example, if I had two ingredients (apples and sugar) and two recipes (apple pie and donuts) how would I know that there are 3 uses of recipes (two because apple pie uses apples and sugar, and one because donuts use sugar)?

I could do this with the following:

```
count = 0
for recipe in Recipe.objects.all():
  count += recipe.ingredients.count()
```

but that generates too many queries.

Is there an easy way to get this number with annotation / aggregation?

Answer (score 1):

We can try like this (to avoid a lot of `DB` hits of course. Use database aggregations).

```
from django.db.models import Count

recipes = Recipe.objects.annotate(count_ingredients=Count('ingredients'))
for recipe in recipes:
    print(recipe.pk, recipe.count_ingredients)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Recipe.ingredients.through.objects.filter(ingredient=YOUR_INGREDIENT_HERE).count()
```

`Recipe.through` is the "secret" table that holds the objects for the many_to_many field, a new
`Recipe_ingredients`(django's default name) object is created. If you want to use how many recipes use the given ingredient you can just filter that table with your ingredient and get the count of it.

For your example these are created: (pseudo)

```
Recipe_ingredients(ingredient=sugar, recipe=apple_pie)
Recipe_ingredients(ingredient=sugar, recipe=doughnut)
Recipe_ingredients(ingredient=apple, recipe=apple_pie)
```

from here you can calculate about anything with that table, if you want to know to the total uses of all the ingredients it is as simple as

```
Recipe.ingredients.through.objects.count()
```

Comment: I was playing around with this using my own models with ManyToMany related tables, and I found that to get to the `through` reference, I had to essentially do: `Recipe.ingredients.through.objects.count()`. What version of Django do you have? I'm currently on 3.2.

Comment: The code I wrote is incorrect, your's is, I don't know how didn't anyone realize that huge error before, lol. All m2m fields have their own through fields, so it is Model.m2m_field.through. Thanks for correcting!

Comment: So incidentally, I'm trying to solve a problem where we have these multi-table composite views in an advanced search interface. It's sophisticated in that you can create and-groups and or-groups and the form submission converts it all to a single `Q` expression and the query is a filter off the root table. We want to split the rows to reflect a true join through 1 of 3 M:M relations. Given the way it's written, where the root model is the only one referenced, using through would be a mammoth rewrite... Is there a way to specify `through` as a component of the `Q` expression?

Comment: ... I doubt it, but doesn't hurt to ask. Just trying to reduce the effort on the rewrite. It might be easier to simply explicitly define the linking tables.

Comment: It's possible, through model is a model with two foreign keys, you can use the lookup syntax on it to go through the relations, but you need to check what are the default reverse names for through tables or you can create though tables explicitly and set the reverse names. Then it is just as easy as `recipe__ingredients_through_reverse_to_recipe__ingredients_through_reverse_to_ingredients__ingredient_field `

Comment: Wow! That's amazing! I thought sure that wouldn't exist.

Comment: Keep in mind the performance implications, though. It does exist but it may be super slow.

Comment: But wait. The main problem is the count and pagination. Would using `through` in the `Q` expressions alter the count of records in the resulting queryset? And would it be slicable for serverside pagination? Because if we compound the results by the M:M records, the current counts reflecting the number of "root table" records should be less than the results from a "true join". I'll play around with it tomorrow, so I'm sure it will be clear when I try it, so I'm just thinking out loud.

Comment: Regarding speed, with serverside pagination, I'm not too concerned. Before that, pages too ages to load. Now every page is under a second.

Answer (score 0):

```
recipes = Recipe.objects.all()
for recipe in recipes:
    print(recipe.ingredient_set.count())
```