# How to use Django's hidden `through` models in a `Q` expression

Tags: django, orm, many-to-many

**TL;DR;** What is the correct way to include a `through` table (for a m2m related table field) in a `Q` expression?  E.g. instead of referencing the m2m field "compounds" in `Q(compounds__name__iexact="citrate")`, how do I reference the hidden through table automatically created when you have a ManyToManyField?  My guess was `Q(through_peakgroup_compound__name__iexact="citrate")`, but that throws an exception.

**Long version**...

I learned yesterday that you can use a `through` expression in a key path^ that's in a `Q` expression.  And I learned that when filtering using fields in M:M related tables, the resulting queryset is more like a true SQL join.  What I mean by this is better explained in my examples below, but the gist is, if I use search terms on fields through m2m relations, I only get back m2m related table records that match those search terms instead of every linked record in that table.

I experimented in the shell and learned that I could accomplish this using `ModelA.m2mModelB.through.filter()`.

For example, I have 56 PeakGroup records that link to the same 2 compounds (citrate and isocitrate) through a many-to-many relation.

This is the closest I could get to what I wanted when I wasn't using `through`:

Querying for citrate only:

```
In [93]: pgs = PeakGroup.objects.filter(Q(compounds__name__iexact="citrate")).distinct()

In [94]: pgs.count()
Out[94]: 56

In [95]: for i in range(0, 56):
    ...:     for compound in pgs[i].compounds.all():
    ...:         print(", ".join(map(lambda s: str(s), [pgs[i].id, pgs[i].name, compound.id, compound.name])))
    ...: 
4, citrate/isocitrate, 12, citrate
4, citrate/isocitrate, 28, isocitrate
11, citrate/isocitrate, 12, citrate
11, citrate/isocitrate, 28, isocitrate
...
```

Note that it gives me unwanted isocitrate records, which in SQL, would not be included in the left-joined rows.  (I was able to get around this case by supplying a `Prefetch` with a queryset using a re-rooted^^ version of the filter, but it re-introduced the problem with the next case, so I won't go into that.)

Querying for citrate or isocitrate:

```
In [90]: pgs = PeakGroup.objects.filter(Q(compounds__name__iexact="citrate") | Q(compounds__name__iexact="isocitrate")).distinct()

In [91]: pgs.count()
Out[91]: 56

In [92]: for i in range(0, 56):
    ...:     for compound in pgs[i].compounds.all():
    ...:         print(", ".join(map(lambda s: str(s), [pgs[i].id, pgs[i].name, compound.id, compound.name])))
    ...: 
4, citrate/isocitrate, 12, citrate
4, citrate/isocitrate, 28, isocitrate
11, citrate/isocitrate, 12, citrate
11, citrate/isocitrate, 28, isocitrate
...
```

The above is good in that, I get everything I queried for, but I can't paginate this if these are displayed on 112 separate rows (each compound is on another row displayed with duplicate PeakGroup data) in the template.

Here's what I get when I *do* use through (this is what I *want*):

Querying for citrate only:

```
In [83]: pgs = PeakGroup.compounds.through.objects.filter(Q(compound__name__iexact="citrate"))

In [84]: pgs.count()
Out[84]: 56

In [85]: for i in range(0, 56):
    ...:     print(", ".join(map(lambda s: str(s), [pgs[i].peakgroup.id, pgs[i].peakgroup.name, pgs[i].compound.id, pgs[i].compound.name])))
    ...: 
4, citrate/isocitrate, 12, citrate
11, citrate/isocitrate, 12, citrate
...
```

^^perfect!

Querying for citrate or isocitrate:

```
In [57]: pgs = PeakGroup.compounds.through.objects.filter(Q(compound__name__iexact="citrate") | Q(compound__name__iexact="isocitrate"))

In [58]: pgs.count()
Out[58]: 112

In [59]: for i in range(0, 112):
    ...:     print(", ".join(map(lambda s: str(s), [pgs[i].peakgroup.id, pgs[i].peakgroup.name, pgs[i].compound.id, pgs[i].compound.name])))
    ...: 
4, citrate/isocitrate, 12, citrate
4, citrate/isocitrate, 28, isocitrate
11, citrate/isocitrate, 12, citrate
11, citrate/isocitrate, 28, isocitrate
18, citrate/isocitrate, 12, citrate
18, citrate/isocitrate, 28, isocitrate
...
```

^^perfect!

However, I learned in the comments under [this stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56398474/2057516), that I should be able to accomplish the same thing in the `Q` expression supplied to a single filter only, without referencing *`.compounds.through`*.  Since accomplishing all this in a single filter off PeakGroup alone would make my refactor massively less involved, I'd like to learn how to do what I was told was possible.

I began to experiment in the shell using trial and error (since I could not find anything in the docs that describe this capability).  I imagined the expression might look something like this:

```py
PeakGroup.objects.filter(Q(through_peakgroup_compound__compound__name__exact="citrate") | Q(through_peakgroup_compound__compound__name__exact="isocitrate")).count()
```

but I have been unable to figure out how to construct the "path" that includes the through model...

Every attempt results in an error something like:

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'through_peakgroup_compound' into field.
```

Perhaps in the comments of that linked stack answer, there was a miscommunication, and this trick is actually not possible via a Q-expression in a single filter applied directoly to `PeakGroup.objects`?  So what is the correct "path" to use instead of "through_peakgroup_compound__compound__name__exact"?

Here's the model relations:

```
class PeakGroup(Model):
    compounds = models.ManyToManyField(
        Compound,
        related_name="peak_groups",
        help_text="The compound(s) that this PeakGroup is presumed to represent.",
    )

class Compound(Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        unique=True,
    )
```

#### Motivation

The reason I'd hoped a single filter with a complex Q expression was possible is because we have a rather large and sophisticated advanced search interface that uses 3 composite views that combine roughly a dozen models each, including a few M:M relations.  Users can construct complex queries with `and`-groups and `or`-groups with terms from any of the models.  Currently, the results combine records from those M:M models using a delimiter in a cell on a single row, but a new requirement for the next release is to split the output rows on one of those M:M related models, so using the example above, one row would display "citrate" and another row would display "isocitrate" in the "Compound" column, instead of currently "citrate; isocitrate" on a single row.  And if they search for "citrate", no row containing "isocitrate" would be among the results.

^ - By "key path", I mean the foreign keys strung together in a path, like what you would supply to a `.filter()` or a `Q` expression, like the **`modelBkey__modelCkey__modelCfieldname`** part of: `ModelA.objects.filter(modelBkey__modelCkey__modelCfieldname__exact="searchterm")` or to include a related field in a template like `{{ queryset.modelBkey.modelCkey.modelCfieldname }}`.

^^ - By "re-rooted version of the filter", I mean, I take the original filter/Q expressions and I change the key paths to start from the m2m related table. It works quite well, but it doesn't solve my whole problem.

Comment: Something's missing from my question but I'm not sure what. I just did a sanity check in the shell by querying `PeakGroup.objects.filter(Q(compounds__name__exact="citrate") | Q(compounds__name__exact="isocitrate")).prefetch_related('compounds__synonyms').count()` and I got a queryset with 212 records. The count reported on our results page for the same query is 106. Maybe I cut back the toy example too much or else there's some other factor... Going to (vote to) delete my question until I can reproduce the problem I'm trying to solve in the shell.

Comment: @Işık Kaplan - So I made a question out of your comment in the other stack post you answered. I have not been able to figure out how to implement your suggestion... Do you have more details you can provide that would allow me to get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless someone is able to demonstrate otherwise, it does not appear to be possible to include a *hidden* `through` table (what I would call an SQL "linking table") in either a `.filter()` of `Q()` expression.  Only **explicitly defined** `through` tables appear to be able to be queried in such a way, e.g.:

```
class PeakGroup(Model):
    compounds = models.ManyToManyField(
        Compound,
        through="Measurement",
        related_name="peak_groups",
        help_text="The compound(s) that this PeakGroup is presumed to represent.",
    )

class Compound(Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        unique=True,
    )

class Measurement(Model):
    peakgroup = ForeignKey(PeakGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    compound = ForeignKey(Compound, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then you can include that table in filter and Q expressions, such as:

```
PeakGroup.objects.filter(Q(measurement__compound__name="citrate") | Q(measurement__compound__name="isocitrate"))
```

**However**, in this case, you still only are sending `PeakGroup` records to the template and the associated Measurement/Compound records must be retrieved anew in a nested `for` loop, so this doesn't allow me to do what I'd hoped it would do.

Note that in the demonstration of what I wanted, I had a flaw that I didn't realize.  I didn't realize that the records that would be sent to the template in the `PeakGroup.compounds.through` case are the linking table records (i.e. the `Measurement` records), not `PeakGroup` records as I had overlooked.  Here's why that's a problem...

If you have multiple linking tables in the view (as I do), you will run into the same problem at the next table, (unless you're sending multiple querysets (which our existing code base does not support)), so using a through/linking table in this manner is not a scalable solution.  It could work for one M:M relation, but no more.

I did figure out a **work-around**, which does solve the overall problem (wanting to display and paginate a single set of query results that go through multiple linking tables as if it was a true SQL left-join).

The basic premise which makes my work-around work is that *before* you send a queryset to the template, a queryset has access to the full/true joined data.  It links each duplicate PeakGroup record with a single Compound record, which is what I need in the template.  You only lose access to those associations when you send the resulting queryset to the template, which is why everyone always simple uses nested `for` loops in templates in Django to display M:M related records.

*Note, Django will give you back duplicate PeakGroup records, each connected to a single `Compound` record (as you would expect in a left join) and you can access it, before sending the queryset to the template, using an `F` expression.*

#### Work-around

*Note, you don't need to explicitly define a `through` table for this to work.*

To take advantage of access to the full-left-join data and embed the M:M associations in the queryset so that they can be reconstructed in the template, you need 2 things:

- A call to `.distinct(join_key_list)`, supplying the primary keys that make the join distinct
- Add calls to `.annotate(**mm_key_values)` that creates an annotation with the M:M related table primary key value (by way of the `F` expression)

Using my first 2 examples, it would look like this:

Querying only for citrate:

```
In [13]: pgs = PeakGroup.objects.filter(Q(compounds__name__iexact="citrate")).distinct('name', 'pk', 'compounds__name', 'compounds__pk').annotate(compound=F("compounds__pk"))
    ...: print(pgs.count())
    ...: for pg in pgs:
    ...:     for cp in pg.compounds.all():
    ...:         if pg.compound == cp.pk:
    ...:             print(f"{pg.pk} {pg.name} {cp.pk} {cp.name}")
    ...: 
56
4 citrate/isocitrate 12 citrate
11 citrate/isocitrate 12 citrate
18 citrate/isocitrate 12 citrate
25 citrate/isocitrate 12 citrate
32 citrate/isocitrate 12 citrate
...
```

Querying for either citrate or isocitrate:

```
In [12]: pgs = PeakGroup.objects.filter(Q(compounds__name__iexact="citrate") | Q(compounds__name__iexact="isocitrate")).distinct('name', 'pk', 'compounds__name', 'compounds__pk').annotate(compound=F("compounds__pk"))
    ...: print(pgs.count())
    ...: for pg in pgs:
    ...:     for cp in pg.compounds.all():
    ...:         if pg.compound == cp.pk:
    ...:             print(f"{pg.pk} {pg.name} {cp.pk} {cp.name}")
    ...: 
112
4 citrate/isocitrate 12 citrate
4 citrate/isocitrate 28 isocitrate
11 citrate/isocitrate 12 citrate
11 citrate/isocitrate 28 isocitrate
18 citrate/isocitrate 12 citrate
18 citrate/isocitrate 28 isocitrate
...
```

It's annoying that you have to loop to filter the unused M:M related records, but this works well, as it allows me to:

1. Get an accurate count of "joined" records.
2. Use server-side pagination
3. Display a "true" representation of an SQL left-join in a template

Note, I do still employ a `.prefetch_related()` (not shown here) to which I supply `Prefetch()` objects that contain a copy of the original filter supplied to the `queryset` option, only the paths supplied in the filter are "re-rooted"^^.  This provides a significant performance boost.

I also wrote a template tag (`simple_tag`) named `get_manytomany_rec` that takes the M:M table records (`pg.compounds.all`) and the annotation field value (e.g. `pg.compound`) and it retrieves the corresponding Compound record for that row.  And I did it in a way that if I set that M:M table to *not* split the result rows, it just returns the supplied `pgs.compounds.all` records.  The usage of the template tag looks like this:

```
{% get_manytomany_rec pg.compounds.all pg.compound as compounds %}
{% for mcpd in compounds %}<a href="{% url 'compound_detail' mcpd.id %}">{{ mcpd.name }}</a>; {% endfor %}
```

*(Note, I have a setting I can flip to either make the M:M related table display as a `;` delimited value on 1 row or make it split the 1 row into multiple rows.)*

I would **love** to have a better/simpler solution than this work-around, but until someone provides a better answer, this was the best I could do.